# How to prove this inequality by induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(v_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers with $v_1=1$ and such that
$$
v_{n+1} \leq v_{n}+ \sqrt{v_{n}^2+1}.
$$
How prove that
$$
v_{n}\leq 2^n-1
$$
for any integer $n \geq 2$?

Comment: First, define $v_n=u_{2^n}$ so you don't haveto heep putting $2^n$ in all the sindices. Then $v_{n+1}\leq v_n+\sqrt{v_n^2+1}$ and you want to prove $v_n\leq 2^n-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a+b$.